# Spring doesnt see one specific module

Tags: spring, configuration, component-scan

In multi module maven project Spring scans everything but one module:

[image]

So, @Component/ @Controller annotations in ui module are being ignored by Spring

[image]

Any other bean is under the reach of the context:

[image]

Spring Config:
[image]

I do believe there is no typo or something. Clean-install, invalidate caches do not work.

Answer (score 0):

Though I didn't find clean info about my mistake, manually moving Main class to the module higher in dependency hierarchy fixed the problem (UI dependes on the Domain which depends on Property and DI modules).